# Apache ECharts with Vue does not show Tooltip

Tags: vue.js, apache-echarts

I'm currently facing the following problem:
I've created a simple line chart and filled it with example data.
But the tooltip doesn't show up.

I've tried using my config on the ECharts Website and there the tooltip is working.

```
option = {
            title: {
              text: 'Baum'
            },
            tooltip: {
              trigger: 'item',
              show: true,
              showContent: true,
              alwaysShowContent: true,
              triggerOn: 'mousemove',
              axisPointer:
                  {
                    label: {
                      show: true,
                    }
                  }
            },
            legend: {
              data: ['lain', 'lain2']
            },
            xAxis:{
              type: 'category',
              data: ['1h', '2h', '3h', '4h', '5h', '6h', '7h', '8h', '9', '10'],
              boundaryGap: false,
            },
            yAxis: {
              type: 'value'
            },
            series: [
              {
                name: 'lain',
                type: 'line',
                showSymbol: true,
                data: [100,199,200,287,345,456,567,600,700,800],
                smooth: true
              },
              {
                name: 'lain2',
                type: 'line',
                showSymbol: true,
                data: [111,158,231,296,374,495,596, 650,750,879],
                smooth: true
              }
            ],
            animationDuration: 2000
          }
}
```

In vue it's implemented like this:

```
<v-chart :options="option"></v-chart>
```

The data in the diagram itself is shown properly.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

The import for the tooltip module has to imported explicitly.

```
import 'echarts/lib/component/tooltip'
```

With this import it's working.