# Vue-echarts: tooltip working on all but one of my charts. Why?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, echarts

I have several echarts in an application I develop. I'm using V4 of echarts (can't upgrade just yet) and following the documentation for tooltip usage as found here: https://echarts.apache.org/v4/en/option.html#tooltip All but my latest one are showing the tooltip just fine. I cannot see any difference between my new one and my old ones.

I have explicitly imported the proper modules as outlined in the answer to this question: [Apache ECharts with Vue does not show Tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64686440/apache-echarts-with-vue-does-not-show-tooltip) just like I did for my old ones.

I use vue files with the template on top, script in the middle, and css at the bottom. The chart is defined in the template thus:

```
<echarts
  id="alertPie"
  :options="option"
  class="alertChart"
  autoresize
/>
```

In my scripts section, I have these imports:

```
import 'echarts/lib/chart/pie'
import 'echarts/lib/component/tooltip'
import 'echarts/lib/component/title'
import 'echarts/lib/component/legend'
```

The "option" for the chart is a computed field defined thus:

```
computed: {
    option () {
      return {
        backgroundColor: '#efefef',
        textStyle: {
          fontStyle: 'italic',
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Alert Adoption',
          subtext: 'Count by Alert',
          left: 'center',
          top: 10,
          textStyle: {
            color: '#ee0022',
            textBorderColor: '#000000',
            textBorderWidth: 2,
            textShadowColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
            textShadowBlur: 4,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            textShadowOffsetX: 2,
            textShadowOffsetY: 2,
            fontSize: 28
          },
          subtextStyle: {
            color: 'black'
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
          trigger: 'item',
          formatter: '{a} <br/>{b} : {c} ({d}%)'
        },
        legend: {
          // orient: 'vertical',
          // top: 'middle',
          bottom: 10,
          left: 'center'
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: 'pie',
            type: 'pie',
            data: this.alertPieData,
            radius: '40%',
            center: ['50%', '40%'],
            selectedMode: 'single',
            itemStyle: {
              emphasis: {
                shadowBlur: 10,
                shadowOffsetX: 0,
                shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        animationDuration: 2000
      }
    }
  }
```

The pie shows the data correctly. The title and legend both show correctly. Of the imported items, only the tooltip is not working.

Like I said, my other charts are built the same and tooltips work. What could I have missed? I've stared at this and compared to my working examples and don't see any differences (other than data sources and title/label changes).

Any ideas?

Data sample below:

```
[ { "name": "Acthar Gel Med Order Alert", "value": 10 }, 
{ "name": "Anticoagulation / Hemoglobin Alert", "value": 6 }, 
{ "name": "Anticoagulation or Dual Antiplatelet / Hemoglobin Alert", "value": 7 }, 
{ "name": "Berinert Alert", "value": 10 }, 
{ "name": "Blood Culture Identification Alert", "value": 13 }, 
{ "name": "Clostridium Difficile Alert", "value": 9 }, 
{ "name": "Clostridium Difficile Lab Order Alert", "value": 15 }, 
{ "name": "Controlled Substance - Pyxis Removal / Late Admin Alert", "value": 13 } ]
```

Comment: Can you share the sample data for this.alertPieData

Comment: @PatelPratik edited to include data sample of approx. 1/4 of the set. It's not big altogether. Maybe 25 pairs is all.

Comment: I have tried this it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this using CDN it should work.

```
<!--
    THIS EXAMPLE WAS DOWNLOADED FROM https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=pie-roseType
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body style="height: 100%; margin: 0">
        <div id="container" style="height: 100%"></div>

        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.3.2/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Uncomment this line if you want to dataTool extension
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.3.2/dist/extension/dataTool.min.js"></script>
        -->
        <!-- Uncomment this line if you want to use gl extension
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts-gl@2/dist/echarts-gl.min.js"></script>
        -->
        <!-- Uncomment this line if you want to echarts-stat extension
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts-stat@latest/dist/ecStat.min.js"></script>
        -->
        <!-- Uncomment this line if you want to use map
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.3.2/map/js/china.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.3.2/map/js/world.js"></script>
        -->
        <!-- Uncomment these two lines if you want to use bmap extension
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.map.baidu.com/api?v=2.0&ak=<Your Key Here>"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@{{version}}/dist/extension/bmap.min.js"></script>
        -->

        <script type="text/javascript">
var dom = document.getElementById("container");
var myChart = echarts.init(dom);
var app = {};

var option;



option = {
        backgroundColor: '#efefef',
        textStyle: {
          fontStyle: 'italic',
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Alert Adoption',
          subtext: 'Count by Alert',
          left: 'center',
          top: 10,
          textStyle: {
            color: '#ee0022',
            textBorderColor: '#000000',
            textBorderWidth: 2,
            textShadowColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
            textShadowBlur: 4,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            textShadowOffsetX: 2,
            textShadowOffsetY: 2,
            fontSize: 28
          },
          subtextStyle: {
            color: 'black'
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
          trigger: 'item',
          formatter: '{a} <br/>{b} : {c} ({d}%)'
        },
        legend: {
          // orient: 'vertical',
          // top: 'middle',
          bottom: 10,
          left: 'center'
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: 'pie',
            type: 'pie',
            data: [ { "name": "Acthar Gel Med Order Alert", "value": 10 }, 
{ "name": "Anticoagulation / Hemoglobin Alert", "value": 6 }, 
{ "name": "Anticoagulation or Dual Antiplatelet / Hemoglobin Alert", "value": 7 }, 
{ "name": "Berinert Alert", "value": 10 }, 
{ "name": "Blood Culture Identification Alert", "value": 13 }, 
{ "name": "Clostridium Difficile Alert", "value": 9 }, 
{ "name": "Clostridium Difficile Lab Order Alert", "value": 15 }, 
{ "name": "Controlled Substance - Pyxis Removal / Late Admin Alert", "value": 13 } ],
            radius: '40%',
            center: ['50%', '40%'],
            selectedMode: 'single',
            itemStyle: {
              emphasis: {
                shadowBlur: 10,
                shadowOffsetX: 0,
                shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        animationDuration: 2000
      } 

if (option && typeof option === 'object') {
    myChart.setOption(option);
}

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Turns out the echart wasn't a problem at all. I am using it within a Quasar Framework (VueJS) project, and for some reason some other element on the page was preventing the tooltip from working. Once I removed that element, everything works. I just really wanted BOTH elements. Oh well. Nevertheless, I'll accept your answer since it shows a working example.

Comment: Here is my repo https://github.com/pratik227/quasar-echarts